# XML file - Using SED to change the value of a property

Tags: xml, sed, awk

I have this xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="emulator-5554_tel_unknown_sdk" name="com.example.android.apis.tests.robotium" tests="3" time="4.4730" timestamp="Thu Jan 16 14:34:09 CET 2014">
      <properties>
         <property name="PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" value="AMD64" />
         <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io" />
      </properties>
   <testcase classname="android.test.AndroidTestCase" name="testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly" time="0.1750" />
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

I am a newbie with sed command. I would like to modify  the name attribute of the testsuite element. I would like to prefix its value with the value of the hostname attribute.

Can I do this kind of think with sed ? Do you have any snippet of code.

Thanks a lot.

Emmanuel

Comment: It's a bad idea to parse `xml` with `sed`. Are you stuck with it?

Comment: If it is a bad idea, what is the best one ?

Comment: `xslt` or any language with a good parser, like `java`, `python`, `perl`, `ruby` and hundreds like them.

Comment: What is the output you like to have from this?

Answer (score 1):

Using Gnu Awk version 4, you could try something like:

```
gawk -f a.awk RS="^$" file.xml
```

where `a.awk` is:

```
{
    n=split($0,a,/<testsuite [^>]*>/,s)
    printf "%s%s",s[0],a[1]
    for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
        m=split(s[i],b,/(name|hostname)="[^"]*"/,t)
        printf "%s%s",t[0],b[1]
        q=length(t[1])
        z=substr(t[1],11,q-11)
        q=length(t[2])
        w=substr(t[2],7,q-7)
        t[2]="name=\""z ":" w "\""
        printf "%s%s%s%s%s%s",t[1],b[2],t[2],b[3],t[3],a[i+1]
    }
    printf "%s", s[n]
}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
   <testsuite errors="0" failures="0" hostname="emulator-5554_tel_unknown_sdk" name="emulator-5554_tel_unknown_sdk:com.example.android.apis.tests.robotium" tests="3" time="4.4730" timestamp="Thu Jan 16 14:34:09 CET 2014">
      <properties>
         <property name="PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE" value="AMD64" />
         <property name="file.encoding.pkg" value="sun.io" />
      </properties>
   <testcase classname="android.test.AndroidTestCase" name="testAndroidTestCaseSetupProperly" time="0.1750" />
   </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```